# pandas: replace values at specifc index in columns of list of strings

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

I have a dataframe as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"first_col":[["a","b","c","d"],["a","b"],["a","b","c"]],
               "second_col":[["the","house","is","[blue]"],["the","[weather]"]["[the]","class","today"]]})
```

I would like to replace values in the first column with the values in the second column if that value is in bracket so, I would like the following output.

output:

```
      first_col                second_col
0  [a, b, c, [blue]]          [the, house, is, [blue]]
1        [a, [weather]]       [the, [weather]]
2     [[the], b, c]           [[the], class, today]
```

I know how to do that for two lists as follows, but do not know how to do it for a pandas dataframe of list columns. so if i have two lists I would do,

```
a =["a","b","c"]
b = ["[the]","class","today"]

for index,item in enumerate(b):
    if item.endswith("]"):
    a[index] = b[index]
```

so printing a would return: [[the], b, c]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a list comprehension:

```
df['first_col'] = [
    [b if b.startswith('[') and b.endswith(']') else a for a, b in zip(A, B)]
    for A, B in zip(df['first_col'], df['second_col'])
]
```

output:

```
           first_col                second_col
0  [a, b, c, [blue]]  [the, house, is, [blue]]
1     [a, [weather]]          [the, [weather]]
2      [[the], b, c]     [[the], class, today]
```